# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fullCalendar' (index):38 (anonymous function)

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, fullcalendar

I am trying to import fullCalendar in my django app

It's not working. I am getting an error as:

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fullCalendar' (index):38

(anonymous function) (index):38

c jquery.js:3048

p.fireWith jquery.js:3160

x.extend.ready jquery.js:433

q

I used noConflict(); also. Still the error is not resolved.

The jQuery is loaded properly. Still the calendar is not displayed.

This is my file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='/home/ttt/ashwini_booktype/Booktype/lib/booki/templates/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='/home/ttt/ashwini_booktype/Booktype/lib/booki/templates/lib/jquery-ui.custom.min.js'></script>
<script src='/home/ttt/ashwini_booktype/Booktype/lib/booki/templates/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script src='/home/ttt/ashwini_booktype/Booktype/lib/booki/templates/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js'></script>
<script src='/home/ttt/ashwini_booktype/Booktype/lib/booki/templates/fullcalendar/gcal.js'></script>
<link href='/home/ttt/ashwini_booktype/Booktype/lib/booki/templates/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css'
    rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link href='/home/ttt/ashwini_booktype/Booktype/lib/booki/templates/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css'
    rel='stylesheet' media='print' type='text/css' />
<script>

    if (typeof jQuery !== 'undefined') {

        console.log('jQuery Loaded');

    }

    else {

        console.log('not loaded yet');

    }


    var j = jQuery.noConflict();

    j(document).ready(function ($) {

        var date = new Date();

        var d = date.getDate();

        var m = date.getMonth();

        var y = date.getFullYear();

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

            editable: true,

            events: [

            {
                title: 'All Day Event',

                start: new Date(y, m, 1)

            },

            {

                title: 'Long Event',

                start: new Date(y, m, d - 5),

                end: new Date(y, m, d - 2)

            },

            {

                id: 999,

                title: 'Repeating Event',

                start: new Date(y, m, d - 3, 16, 0),

                allDay: false

            },

            {

                id: 999,

                title: 'Repeating Event',

                start: new Date(y, m, d + 4, 16, 0),

                allDay: false

            },

            {

                title: 'Meeting',

                start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),

                allDay: false

            },

            {

                title: 'Lunch',

                start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),

                end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),

                allDay: false

            },

            {

                title: 'Birthday Party',

                start: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 19, 0),

                end: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 22, 30),

                allDay: false

            },

            {

                title: 'Click for Google',

                start: new Date(y, m, 28),

                end: new Date(y, m, 29),

                url: 'http://google.com/'

            }

        ]

        });



    });



</script>
<style>
    body
    {
        margin-top: 40px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-family: "Lucida Grande" ,Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
    }

    #calendar
    {
        width: 900px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width: 800px height: 600px;">
    <div id='calendar'>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try running your code after the div with id "calendar"